# "Opposite" of chi-square test of goodness of fit (akin to a linear regression between predicted and observed values)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, predictive-models, count-data, multinomial-distribution

Suppose I have observed count data $x_1,...,x_k$. I have a hypothesis that this data was drawn from a multinomial distribution (derived from theory) with event probabilities $p_1,...,p_k$.

It is simple to construct a test to reject the null hypothesis that my observed data comes from this predicted distribution: I simply perform a chi-square goodness of fit test.

What I instead want to do is to construct a test to reject the null hypothesis that this hypothesized distribution did *not* generate any of the observed counts. Or, another way to put it, if the count data $x_1,...,x_k$ was generated by a multinomial mixture distribution $w(p_1,...,p_k)+(1-w)(q_1,...,q_k)$, where $p_1,...,p_k$ are a predicted distribution (i.e. fixed ahead of time), I want to test whether $w$ is significantly different from zero.

To me this seems somewhat analogous to a linear regression between a vector of observed values and a vector of predicted values: the test statistic is maximized (and p-value minimized) when the predicted values exactly match the observed values; also, the $r^2$ value of this test gives information about the proportion of the variance in my observed values that is explained by my predicted values, in the same way that $w$ above gives some information about the proportion of counts in my count data that are "explained" by my predicted distribution. But I have no idea whether this is doable for count data (especially because it seems like setting $w$ to zero and $q_1,...,q_k$ to the observed frequencies will always maximize likelihood...).

Is there a way to actually do this?

Comment: How would you do this for a linear regression?

Comment: There exists no such test, because there is no way to distinguish the distributions of *any* test statistic based on your putative null from the hypothesized distribution.  The problem is that the two kinds of distributions you wish to distinguish are arbitrarily close to each other.  For discussions of where this approach can be made to work, see our posts about [TOST](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=TOST).

Comment: @Dave suppose I had numerical observations $y_1,...,y_n$, and a theory about how they came to be that yielded predicted numerical observations $x_1,...,x_n$. It seems to me that a test of the significance of the $\beta_1$ coefficient in $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X$ tests whether there is any information in the prediction? Vs. if you shuffled the order of the observations, wouldn't $E[\beta_1] = 0$? (also @whuber) In this way, would it be valid to do a permutation test where you shuffled the category labels on your count data, and used the likelihood under $p_1,...,p_k$ as test statistic?